# Construction of the trace ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

Could someone help me to understand what is the trace ring of a prime PI-algebra, I have some difficulties in its construction and I can't find a reference in the web
Thank you so much

Comment: See for example [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=LWXUCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA17&lpg=PA17&dq=trace+ring+of+a+prime+PI-algebra&source=bl&ots=0SPAU3f75f&sig=yv3Yv8q1gV9Y0ZaNRfm2YJGV6DM&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiA5cXIyYDbAhWBMewKHT2qBv4Q6AEIQzAD#v=onepage&q=trace%20ring%20of%20a%20prime%20PI-algebra&f=false).

Comment: Yes I'm studing this paper, but i didn't understand this notion very well, I wonder if there exists another ref, thank u

Comment: See for example [this paper](https://msp.org/pjm/1991/150-1/pjm-v150-n1-p03-p.pdf).